# Firebase Cloud Function Uncaught Exceptions - Do They Cause a Cold Start?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Likely an easy question for somebody in the know...

I was reading the documentation for Firebase Cloud Functions and GCP Cloud Functions and I noticed that there is a difference in the recommended approach for handling errors. This surprised me because my understanding is that Firebase Cloud Functions are very closely related to GCP Cloud Functions.

In the [Firebase documentation on error reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors) it indicates that an error may be thrown to get it into StackDriver, as follows:

`throw new Error('Fail!');`

Meanwhile, the [GCP Cloud Function documentation on error reporting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) states that uncaught exceptions force a cold start on a future invocation. Instead, the following is suggested:

`console.error(new Error('Fail!'));`

Does throwing the Error directly also cause a cold start on Firebase Cloud Functions? On Firebase, does sending the error to the console avoid this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for Cloud is correct.  At this moment, the Firebase docs need to be updated to match the changes that were made for Cloud.

An instance will be restarted after a function throws 3 exceptions. It's likely in your best interest to `catch` after every `then` chain, and log the error with `console.error()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful.

Comment: Hey, Doug. Is a `throw new https.HttpsError(...)` safe to use inside a https callable function to avoid cold start and yet providing semantic response to users? As of today, is there any Firebase specific documentation about this use case? Thank you